# Can a useMemo memoized value be updated with useEffect from within the component?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-usememo

I'm trying to render data that must be passed through `useMemo`. I get the data from an api call so I call `useEffect`. The initial render works returning an empty array but once I call the api, data is not updated.

```
import React from 'react'
import {fetchAccounts} from '../utils/api'

export default function Accounts() {
    const [accounts, setAccounts] = React.useState([])

React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    fetchAccounts().then((data) => {
        setAccounts(data)
    })
}, [])
const data = React.useMemo(() => accounts, [])

return <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>}
```

So can this work within a single component? Or must a custom hook be created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data is not updated because you missing a value in the dependency array.

```
const data = React.useMemo(() => accounts, [accounts]);
```

Therefore in this case, it does not make sense to use `useMemo` since the state is stable anyways, till you change the state.

Answer (score 3):

You use **useMemo** and **useEffect** with the dependency of [] means it run during mounting means it run for once's

Let see How useMemo() works

1. It will run every time if any change occur

   useMemo(()=>{

   })
2. It will run once's during component mounting

   useMemo(()=>{

   },[])
3. It will run every time if any changes occur in **arr**

   useMemo(()=>{

   },[arr])

If you have confusion what is the difference between useEffect() and useMemo()

useMemo() is only run when it find any changes it compare latest changes with the previous changes if it find any changes then **useMemo** run

useEffect() is run for every changes if the updated state is same as previous state useEffect don't care it start re render the component.